# Regenerate contour lost parts

Tags: qgis, contour

I have some countour datasets where some parts were cut by labels, like this:

[image: Contours]

Can these parts be regenerated? What I've tried is to create a straigth line between the dangling ends, but there are many cases where the created line overlaps other contours.

Another option I've tried is generate contours with the QGIS 'Countour plugin' but to make it work, I must use a high value of point thinning with a result far from what I've expected.

Comment: Do you have access to the original height data?

Comment: No, was made by another company we don't know. :(

Comment: ET Geowizards has a specific tool for this called [Clean Contour Gaps](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm), but given the size of some of those gaps I'm not sure it would be very effective as it relies on a gap tolerance. From the examples shown, manual editing might be the cleanest way to do it. You could also try creating a surface from contours and then reverting that back to contours, but that's going to be a more significant degradation (or at least altering) of data.